# Google+ Sharing in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, google-plus

I am developing a web application for PC/Tablet/Mobile phones, and I want to integrate Google+ Sharing onto it.

But seems that the url https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com has blocking iframes...

prove that it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/6ML4d/

isn't there any other way to do that?

P.S The server side of my application is ASP.NET MVC and the client side is jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Can't you integrate the [+1 Button](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/) or [Share](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/share/) button?

Comment: @ephemient +1 or share button, may open a popup window if user has not logged in. But in Tablet and Mobile phones, opening a popup window is not such a good idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that there are some pages on google servers which allow iframes, but they are not complete . (for example, if user is not logged in, again we have another problem)

So, the best choice is **not using iframes!**

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this chrome extension:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pfphgaimeghgekhncbkfblhdhfaiaipf
It allows you to view your google+ notifications. The developer made it in some way possible to embed something on https://plus.google.com that normally isn't possible.

Comment: Is it possible to view the source of that extension??

Comment: Yep, it is. You can install the application, and view the source on your computer in appdata/local/google/chrome/user data/[your profile name]/extensions/[id of extension]/  . tell me if you succeed embedding google+

Comment: Here, where? What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry my bad english... I mean, what is embedded here that is not normal?

Comment: it is embedding a site on plus.google.com. but sites on plus.google.com are normally not embeddedable. the extension is using google.com/404 to be able to embed the extension in a google site that is embeddable, so you can embed it. if you installed the extension, you can view this: http://www.google.com/404?extension=surplus

Comment: Take a look at the code, sorry, I don't know how he did it :(

Answer (score 0):

> Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.

[See here for supposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6666423/561731)

Comment: I didn't found any solution for my problem in that link.